# How to prevent accessing post route directly by user and how to check a request is empty in laravel 5?

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, request

Here are my routes in my laravel 5 application,

```
Route::get('demotest', 'HomeController@demo_test');
```

`Route::post('demo_result', 'HomeController@demo_result');`


In my first route **view** i have a from with action `{{ url('demo_result') }}` if a user submits the form it will post to my second route and everything working fine, here after submitting form my route changing to `demo_result` which is an post route.
Now the problem is if any user directly trying to access `demo_result` it is showing following error.[image]
So how to handle the issue. I tried to check whether the request is empty but no use. I am using `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to handle request.

Comment: Route::any('demo_result', 'HomeController@demo_result');.. used any and used isset function in demo_result function

Comment: @BilalAhmed thanks i solved my issue by using `Route::any()`.

Comment: your welcome......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any` instead of `get` or `post` and then by using `isset` you can write your own login. Try this `Route::any();`

Answer (score 0):

Method not allowed means you haven't declared a GET method for your demo_result URL.

What you can do I think is just creating a new route

```
Route::get(demo_result', ...);
```

That point to a custom method in your controller that redirect the user to your form, like

```
public function getResult(){ return redirect('demo_form');
```

When you are not posting data and just visiting the page from your browser you are asking a different method, not what you have declared.

Another way is just to set up a 404 handler...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even to handle a 404 first i need to know whether  the request is valid or invalid or atleast the POST data is empty, i tried for it but shows the error i mentioned above. Anyway i solved my issue by using `Route::any()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your Render Function in

> app\Exceptions\handler.php

like:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {   
         if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
             return redirect('/');
         }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```